# Showing sequence $ a_n = \frac{1}{3+2 \cdot (-1)^{n} } $ does not converge

Tags: sequences-and-series

I created the sequence $ a_n = \frac{1}{3+2 \cdot (-1)^{n} } $ and I know it does not converge since it jumps between the values $ 1/5 $ and $ 1 $ , but I had difficulty proving this using definition of limit ( so I can't use Bolzano-Weierstrass or anything related to subsequences ). Naively, I tried assuming that there does exist a limit $ L $ but got stuck:

**Attempt:**
Assume there exists $ L \in R $ s.t. $ \forall \epsilon>0. \exists N \in \mathbb{N}.\forall n>N. |\frac{1}{3+2  \cdot (-1)^{n} } -L | < \epsilon  $

[ I know that $ | \frac{1}{3+2  \cdot (-1)^{n} } + \frac{1}{3+2  \cdot (-1)^{n+2} } | = | \frac{2}{3+2  \cdot (-1)^{n} } | $  and $ | \frac{1}{3+2  \cdot (-1)^{n} } + \frac{1}{3+2  \cdot (-1)^{n+1} } | = 0 $
Maybe I can use this fact to create some inequality in which I can use the assumption in order to reach contradiction. I got to dead end attempting that. Any ideas? ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it converges to $L$, then there is some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that$$n\geqslant N\implies\left|\frac1{3+2(-1)^n}-L\right|<\frac25.$$Let $n_1,n_2\geqslant N$ be such that $n_1$ is odd and $n_2$ is even. Then\begin{align}\left|\frac1{3+2(-1)^{n_1}}-\frac1{3+2(-1)^{n_2}}\right|&=\left|\left(\frac1{3+2(-1)^{n_1}}-L\right)-\left(\frac1{3+2(-1)^{n_2}}-L\right)\right|\\&<\frac25+\frac25\\&=\frac45.\end{align}But$$\left|\frac1{3+2(-1)^{n_1}}-\frac1{3+2(-1)^{n_2}}\right|=\left|1-\frac15\right|=\frac45.$$

Answer (score 1):

Nice start. If the inequality you mentioned holds for all $n\gt N$, then it must hold for $N+1$ and $N+2$. One of these is even and the other is odd, so it must be that both of these hold: $$|\frac 15 -L | \lt \epsilon \iff \frac 15 -\epsilon \lt L \lt \frac 15 +\epsilon \\ |1-L| \lt \epsilon \iff 1-\epsilon \lt L\lt 1+\epsilon $$ But this is easily seen to be false for, say, $\epsilon =0.1$.